# How to stop page reload using async function javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I am working with javascript and right now i am using "async function",Problem is
whenever i click on "complete listing"(button) then page is refreshing,I just want page should not reload after click,How can i stop this,Here is my current code

```
async function completeListing(elm){
        alert("Hello world");
}

<input type="submit" id="nft_forms" name="listing" class="btn btn-primary" value="Complete listing" onclick="completeListing(this)" >
```

Comment: Add `elm.preventDefault()` as the first line in your click listener function.

Answer (score 0):

You set the input to submit:

```
<input type="submit" ...
```

so submitting the form (i.e. sending it to the server and reloading the page) is what a click should do.

If you don't want that, you have several options:

- Use a `<button type="button">`, which will not trigger the submit. This is the preferred solution if you never want to submit through that button.
- Stop the click event from reaching the form by calling `event.stopPropagation()` in the handler. This is the preferred solution if submission might be cancelled due to a condition specific to the button.
- Set a handler on the form that stops submission with `event.preventDefault()`, which is preferred if submission depends on overall conditions (like validation), no matter what triggered it.